# Semaphore tryAcquire() method does not return immediately

Tags: java

The method `tryAcquire(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` in Semaphore does not return immediately. The threads are not blocked and all threads are allowed to acquire the semaphore even though one of the threads is acquiring the semaphore.
I am trying to implement flow control for publishing messages when a broker is notifying the subscribers about the state information change from the previous publish message on the same topic.

I have made a first thread acquiring the semaphore to sleep for 10 seconds before releasing the semaphore and in the meantime, I made another thread to acquire the semaphore while the first thread is still sleeping for 10 seconds and the second thread can still acquire the semaphore. I would like the program to return immediately if the semaphore is not available.
Don't know what's the issue. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

```
try {

if(semaphore.tryAcquire(this.request_handling_time, 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
updateResource(resource, request);
response = channel.createResponse(request, CoapResponseCode.Changed_204);   
                                        logger.info("content changed");                                 
try {

if(request.getMaxAgeTopic()>=0) {

((PubSubTopic) resource).setmaxAgeTopicValue(request.getMaxAgeTopic());
}
}catch(NullPointerException ex){

    if(((PubSubTopic) resource).getmaxAgeTopicValue() > 0){
        ((PubSubTopic) resource).updateTopicLifeTime();
    }
}                                   
resource.changed(); // send notifications to the subscribers

// send notifications to the pendingRequest Clients if present
if(((PubSubTopic) resource).getPendingSubscribe().size() > 0) {
    ((PubSubTopic) resource).notifyPendingRequest();
}           
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);        


    }
    catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") InterruptedException e){
     /*do nothing*/
  }

semaphore.release();
}else {
    logger.info("Too many requests on topic "+resource.getPath());                                  
 response = channel.createResponse(request, 
 CoapResponseCode.Too_Many_Requests_429);   

 response.setMaxAge(retry_time_after_too_many_requests);
                                    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
semaphore.release();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> *`tryAcquire(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method in Semaphore does not return immediately.*

It's not supposed to. If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), you find:

> If no permit is available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and **lies dormant until** one of three things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the release() method for this semaphore and the current thread is next to be assigned a permit; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread; or
> - **The specified waiting time elapses**.

If you want it to return immediately, call [`tryAcquire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire--) (without parameters):

> If no permit is available then this method will **return immediately** with the value `false`.